# adding custom marks to SwiftUI chart using path

Tags: swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

I want to use a custom shape that I have drawn using a path to the marks of my chart. So instead of points or bars or whatever marking the data, I want the shape to be a specific symbol I have drawn. I am quite new to swift so I apologise if I add unnecessary information.

So I have a graph that looks like this:

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qphge.png)

here is the code for it:

```
Chart {
     PointMark(x: .value("Boat", "Pace Boat"), y: .value("Pace Boat", (viewModel.duration*(Double(viewModel.split) / paceBoat))))
                            
     PointMark(x: .value("Boat", "You"), y: .value("Your Pace", viewModel.boat.last?.1.distance ?? 0))
}
```

This is code for the way I produce a shape:

```
struct BoatShape: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        //... do drawing blah
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        
        return path
    }
}
```

I have seen I might be able to use the ChartSymbolShape protocol but I can't find much on the internet on implementation and I am quite new to swift. Any direction would be much appreciated

Additionally:
I would like to be to add text over the top of the shape just sort of pinning it to the x and y of the shape on the graph. Although this is not the main priority

Answer (score -1):

Basically, what you should be doing is use any of the marks provided by Apple however set the opacity to 0 so that they don't appear. And then use the annotation therein you render your view.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the annotation therein"?